What is a good way to troubleshoot matter devices and their connection issues?
I am looking for a way to troubleshoot why matter devices are not connecting at all for initial setup, and/or falling offline/online seemingly at random.
For devices supporting Matter, I have been able to connect them when in my house without issues. When I go out to my detached garage, sometimes I have had success with them connecting, and sometimes not. Once they are initialized, which feels like a random amount of luck to accomplish, they will sometimes go offline until I unplug and plug them back in. This might be weeks later, or it might be a day or two.
In terms of network connectivity, the garage is probably better than most houses, and has its own fiber connection to the house, and its own access point. I have no troubles with internet/network out there. I also have a homepod mini out there, which I believe I'm interpreting as being a good thing to help bridge matter devices to the rest of my matter devices that are in the house? I also just enabled IPv6 locally, to see if that can help with their communications. All iot devices are on their own network, and with a few exceptions, can talk to anything they want on it. (I make sure my phone is also on that same network when setting them up.)
The bottom line though...is that it is very unclear to me why things are failing to connect. Is there any good way to gain insights into what the health of the matter devices is? Is there a way to see how they're trying to communicate and how that is working? It feels like I'm stuck with trust in individual device manufacturers to handle the errors and be helpful, and they do not seem to be helpful in that regard. I feel like I could troubleshoot issues if the errors received when attempting to connect a matter device to the network were more transparent? Am I missing something obvious here in how to tackle errors with Matter devices?
